# Evil mode interacting with python.el (invoking skeletons)

Tags: init-file, evil, python

Skeletons such as `python-skeleton-if` in `python.el` has been giving me problems - I never use them but they get invoked unexpectedly. If they are invoked, it is a pain to get out of it and also it messes up my code.

I tried to use `python-mode` instead of `python.el` but it seems it gets loaded by other packages (such as `lisp/cedet/semantic/wisent/python.elc`) when I look at `load-history` and thus whenever I open a `.py` file `python.el` is always loaded.

Since the skeletons are my main issue, I was wondering if there is a way to completely disable all the skeletons?

---- Edited ----

It seems like Evil mode is interaction with `python.el`. Specifically, `evil-normal-state` after typing `if` invokes `python-skeleton-if`.

For example, if I type `if` and then press ESC, it invokes `python-skeleton-if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In turns out that `evil-mode` was calling `expand-abbrev` because `expand-abbrev` was in `evil-insert-state-exit-hook`. Having `(setq evil-want-abbrev-expand-on-insert-exit nil)` before loading evil fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
(setq python-skeleton-autoinsert nil)
```

?

Comment: Yes its value is `nil` already. It actually seems like an issue about python.el and evil mode interacting. I edited my question accordingly.